# iTunes 11 does not sync apps updated OTA

Tags: itunes

With earlier versions of iTunes, if I updated an app OTA, the next time I synced my phone, iTunes would download the new version to my local library. However, this does not happen anymore. I have to manually check for newer versions of apps in iTunes and then download them again. Is this by design, or am I missing something? I am on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Not by design, it downloads them locally in the most recent version for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to download again, next time you plug in the phone:
in itunes right click on phone and tell it to transfer purhases.

i do this pretty regularly since i have multiple devices and don't need to download each app 4 times.  download on phone / transfer purchases to itunes / sync to others.